# NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code when conducting a unit test sequence

Tags: string, unit-testing, nullreferenceexception

I apologise is this is a duplication of a question already asked elsewhere, but after going through many similar questions, and not seeing an answer that completely matches my situation, I thought it would be best to share my situation, and request ideas/help for fixing the problem.

I have an object which is the beginning of a domain object, which also has a function testing for validity for persistence to a database. The code for this is below:

```
public class DBObject
{
    public string AttributeA { get; set; }
    public string AttributeB { get; set; }
    public string AttributeC { get; set; }

    public bool IsValidForPersistence()
    {
        if (AttributeC.Equals(String.Empty) || AttributeC == null || AttributeB == null || AttributeB.Equals(String.Empty) || AttributeA == null || AttributeA.Equals(String.Empty))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

If I then create a unit test sequence which sets up this object, and tests the if statement in the IsValidForPersistence() method, I get successful tests on all but the AttributeC == null portion. For some reason, the test crashes and gives me the NullReferenceException above. AttributeC should be null (I have set it to that deliberately to test that the if condition works properly). AttributeA and AttributeB both work properly when they are set to null in exactly the same way. I have confirmed through the Local Property inspector in VS2013(Web) that the DBObject is NOT null (and it isn't - it is properly formed - only the AttributeC is null - which matches what I would expect to see). I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the solution, and this also has not cleared the issue.

I know I could work around the problem by using some basic DDD methodologies (such as creating a constructor that forces the user code to fill in AttributeC to ensure it is never actually null), but i'm more interested to know how the error I am getting is coming about, and what I can do to ensure it doesn't happen again in future. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for null before you try invoking a method on the instance. In this particular case you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` like this:

```
return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeA) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeB) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeC))
```

Comment: Ok, great stuff! You have helped me remove the ugly if statement with a more elegant line of code - I appreciate that. However this does not help me to understand why only AttributeC is causing the error, while AttributeA and AttributeB, in the exact same situation do not. +1 however, as it is still a helpful post (once I get the rep)!

Comment: It also resolves the problem - so will mark as solution to boot.

Comment: Because for AttributeA and AttributeB you first check if it is null and the conditions inside the `if` clause in C# are not evaluated if the result is known, so in case of `AttributeB == null || AttributeB.Equals(string.Empty)` the portion `AttributeB.Equals(string.Empty)` will never be evaluated if `AttributeB` is null. In case of AtrributeA the order is different and therefore if `AttributeA` is `null` the first check effectively becomes `null.Equals(string.Empty)` which throws the NullReferenceException. While `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` is preferred way you can use `string.Empty` to avoid NRE

Comment: Aha! So a moment of complete newbishness on my part then. Thanks for the help! :)